# INDEX and MATCH with skipping a few rows

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, excel-2010, match

I have range of E6:E52 but I want to skip a few rows and refer to range E58:E64 as well, is this possible?

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(E6:E52,MATCH(MAX(E6:E52),E6:E52,0)),0,-2)
```

Comment: Try `=INDEX(C6:C52,MATCH(MAX(E6:E52),E6:E52,0))` instead of the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592). I'm unclear on what you mean by 'skip a few rows'.

Comment: E6:E52 is a continuous range then I am trying to break the continuous range and refer to E58:E64 as well. The objective of this formula is to find the max value and offset 2.

Comment: Are any of the entries within the ranges being queried empty? Or do they all contain a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to force some rows into an error state. Using the *Ignore Errors* option parameter (e.g. **6**) should grant the discontiguous cell range and the [MAX function](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/max-function-f7bec1eb-9c66-489a-9166-51d2c9d19333) can have discontiguous cell ranges in its parameters.

```
=INDEX(C6:C64, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:59)/(((ROW(1:59)<48)+(ROW(1:59)>52))*(E6:E64=MAX(E6:E52, E58:E64))), 1))
```

You will have to apply some absolute cell reference markers (e.g. `$C$6:$C$64`) if you plan to copy that to a new location.

[image: AGGREGATE Union of cells]

For all intents and purposes, you are creating the equivalent of a VBA [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa213609(v=office.11).aspx) of non-contiguous cells for the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: =OFFSET(INDEX(E6:E96,MATCH(AGGREGATE(4,6,E7:E20,E28:E32,E37:E44,E49:E71,E77:E95),E6:E96,0)),0,-2)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what your looking for but here goes

```
=INDEX((P6:P13)&(R6:R13),MATCH(MAX(P6:R13),P6:P13,0))
```

I have in columns P6:P13 512 521 522 544 and in columns R6:R13 512 521 522 533

This gives the result
544533

Comment: If you can send me your excel sheet to have a better understanding of what your trying to achieve then I would gladly take a look.